# Get the filePath from Filename using Java

Tags: java, file, filepath

Is there a easy way to get the filePath provided I know the Filename?

Comment: You mean you have the name of a file and want to get the path? What about if there are many files named like this?

Comment: yes. i wanted to know if there is any oneliner code which will get the path of a already xisting file. I think i will have to search through the directories and then list the files.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the `Path` api:

```
Path p = Paths.get(yourFileNameUri);
Path folder = p.getParent();
```

Comment: i am still using java version "1.6.0_31". I suppose Path api comes with Java 1.7

Answer (score 18):

Look at the methods in the [java.io.File class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

```
File file = new File("yourfileName");
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: i already have a file name 'file1.txt' and is stored in D:\\IM\\EclipseWorkspaces\\runtime-EclipseApplication\\Proj\\Software and If a do File file = new File("file1.txt"); and get the file.getAbsolutePath, it gives me D:\\IM\\EclipseVersions\\EclipseSDK3_7\\file1.txt. which is not i want.

Comment: like you said in your comment under the post: you can't avoid traversing directories.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure I understand you completely, but if you wish to get the absolute file path provided that you know the relative file name, you can always do this:

```
System.out.println("File path: " + new File("Your file name").getAbsolutePath());
```

The File class has several more methods you might find useful.

Answer (score 8):

Correct solution with "File" class to get the directory - the "path" of the file:

```
String path = new File("C:\\Temp\\your directory\\yourfile.txt").getParent();
```

which will return:

```
path = "C:\\Temp\\your directory"
```

Comment: getParent() returns a String. Would need to change `File path` to `String path`

Comment: You can use getParentFile()

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(new String()).toAbsolutePath();
```

or

```
FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(new String("./")).toAbsolutePath().getParent()
```

This will give you the root folder path without using the name of the file. You can then drill down to where you want to go.

Example: `/src/main/java...`